# apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk doesn't install javac. Why?

Tags: apt, java

```
The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:
 * openjdk-6-jdk
 * ecj
 * gcj-4.4-jdk
 * gcj-4.6-jdk
 * gcj-4.5-jdk
 * openjdk-7-jdk
```

Then I run `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk` and everything works. But then `javac` still does not exist and I get the same error as above. Same thing with `openjdk-6-jdk`. Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As long as the install completed without errors, there *is* a javac executable on your system; it for some reason just didn't get correctly linked to /usr/bin. `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/bin/javac /usr/bin/javac` will create that link and should fix your problem.

Comment: What if it is not installed properly. I don't see javac in the directory itself.

Answer (score 24):

The proper Debian/Ubuntu way to configure which `javac` is pointed to by `/usr/bin/javac` is to use the `update-alternatives` command. You can do it interactively, and select from a list of available options:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Or you can specify which option you want on the command-line:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/bin/javac
```

Because of the way it stores the information, using `update-alternatives` is not exactly equivalent (but instead is considered preferable) to manually making `/usr/bin/java` a symbolic link to your `javac` of choice. See [`man update-alternatives`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/update-alternatives.8.html) for more information about this.

If `update-alternatives` doesn't work, then run this command and try again:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/alternatives/javac /usr/bin/javac
```

Answer (score 14):

Here's what I did.  It worked.

First I installed the jdk for Java 7 like this:

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`

That might be enough: check and see if javac in your PATH by running `javac -version`

If not, then follow Nicholas' answer except that instead of `sudo update-alternatives --config javac` use this:

`sudo update-alternatives --config java`

And selected Java 7 at at the the prompt by typing `2`:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1051      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this helps, but it worked for me. I had this problem, *javac* was simply not there, anywhere, probably because I only installed the *jre*. Installing the *jdk* after the *jre* fixed it.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Afterwhich set the configurations by following the prompt:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Then you can check if you configured correctly with:

```
java -version
javac -version
```